# Como colocar um contato do sistema em EditText?

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um aplicativo onde o usuário ira clicar em um `EditText` que levará até a lista de contatos do sistema, onde ele irá clicar e o nome do contato aparecerá no `EditText`. Porém, é justamente de pegar este contato e preencher o `EditText` que estou travado. Meu código é esse:

```
Comvoce3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Comvoce);

    Comvoce3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentList = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intentList, RESULT_PICK);
            Comvoce3.setHint("");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Coloque o código, não a imagem do código se quiser obter alguma resposta aqui no SO.

Comment: Coloquei, Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente implementar o result da Activity (já que está utlizando `startActivityForResult`):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RESULT_PICK) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contact = cursor.getString(column);

            Comvoce3.setHint(contact);
        }
    }
}
```